# XOR-ing two objects

Tags: ruby

I have to XOR two objects and thought I could use Ruby's built-in XOR operator (`^`) but it doesn't work. I wanted to use it to test that exactly one of my objects was initialized.

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new
a ^ b # => NoMethodError: undefined method `^' for #<Object:0x007...>
```

Interestingly, I can do

```
a = nil
b = Object.new
a ^ b # => true
```

I think it's odd that Ruby doesn't allow you to XOR two objects innately. Is there another command I'm missing or was this functionality just not built?

Obviously a solution to my problem is to just do the following:

```
(a || b) && !(a && b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new
c = nil
!a ^ !b # => false
!a ^ !c # => true
```

Comment: Woah that's a really clever way to do it.

Comment: @sawa That would be `!a && !b` (or `!(a || b)`).

Answer (score 0):

> Interestingly, I can do

```rb
a = nil
b = Object.new
a ^ b # => true
```

That's because `NilClass` has `nil ^ obj` method.

> Is there another command I'm missing or was this functionality just not built?

It wasn't built.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `^` the operator (actually a method) for your objects. Something like:

```
class YourObject
  def ^(rhs)
    # You may want to do a check here that 
    #   rhs is of the same type as your object,
    #   and throw an error if not
   (self || rhs) && !(self && rhs)
  end
end
```

I recommend you substitute your own class rather than changing Object.

Comment: This code can be shortened. Why not just return `(self || rhs) && !(self && rhs)` because it is already boolean.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yeah, you're totally right. I usually notice the `if (true) return true` thing. Thanks.